# How to access the php.ini from cPanel?

Tags: php, post, cpanel

I want to change the limit of the PHP POST array from 1000 to 6000. Is there any way to do that?
I searched it and found that I should change some variables in php.ini but the problem is that I did not find the directory of the file in my cPanel:

```
Your server's php.ini file is located at /usr/local/lib/php.ini.
```

This line is from the CPanel documentation but i could not find this directory in my cpanel even after i show the hidden files????
can anybody help me locating this file?

Comment: Yes, you can achieve this using an `.htaccess` file - you don't actually have to edit the `php.ini` file, which on shared hosting you often don't have access to.  See https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1658/Using+.htaccess+files#gs

Answer (score 23):

Cpanel 60.0.26 (Latest Version)
Php.ini moved under Software > Select PHP Version > Switch to Php Options > Change Value > save.

Answer (score 5):

If you're on a shared hosting environment you won't have access to the php.ini to make these changes, if you need access, a virtual private server (VPS) or a dedicated server may be a better option if you're confident in managing it yourself.

Alternatively if you create a new file called .htaccess in your root of your web directory (Ensure it doesn't contain a .txt extension if using notepad to create the file) and copy something like this inside.

```
php_value settingToChange 6000
```

This will only work if your hosting provider let's you override the certain config value. Best to ask if it doesn't work after trying.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue in `cPanel 92.0.3` and it was solved through this solution:

In `cPanel`  go to  the below directory

```
software --> select PHP version--> option--> upload_max_filesize
```

Then choose the `optional size` to upload your files.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to find it via the command line.

```
find / -type f -name "php.ini"
```

Or you could add the following to a `.htaccess` file in the root of your site.

```
php_value max_input_vars 6000
php_value suhosin.get.max_vars 6000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 6000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 6000
```

Comment: I try the comment and it shows the same usr/local/...... but i can not find this place on the cpanel account

Comment: `vi /usr/local/lib/php.ini` from the command line, it will open the document up, scroll down to the lines you need to edit, hit `i` edit the numbers, hit `esc`, type `w` hit return, type `q` hit return. done

Answer (score 2):

In cPanel search for php, You will find "Select PHP version" under Software.

Software -> Select PHP Version -> Switch to Php Options -> Change Value -> save.

Answer (score 1):

Go to main screen. Under 'Software/Services' > 'php.ini EZConfig'.

Comment: cPanel 2022 version. On cPanel homepage, go to SOFTWARE > MultiPHP INI Editor

Answer (score 1):

Search for "php version" at the bottom of the cpanel

Select PHP Version -> Switch to Php Options -> Change the Value -> save.

Comment: the simpleast way to change php ini for your project  i use it its good

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it on shared hosting , Add ticket to support of hosting for same ( otherwise you can look for dedicated server where you can manage anything )